# Rolling mean and median for panel data in R

Tags: r, group-by, rolling-computation, panel-data

I have a panel data:

| Date | ID | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Mon | A | 10 |
| Tue | A | 11 |
| Wed | A | 15 |
| Thu | A | 12 |
| Mon | B | 11 |
| Tue | B | 13 |
| Wed | B | 12 |
| Thu | B | 13 |
| Mon | C | 14 |
| Tue | C | 10 |
| Wed | C | 13 |
| Thu | C | 12 |

I would like to create a new column that whihc is the rolling mean, say K = 2, of all the 3 ID.

So in the end I should have something like this:

| Date | ID | Value | RollingMean |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Mon | A | 10 | NA |
| Tue | A | 11 | NA |
| Wed | A | 15 | 11.5 |
| Thu | A | 12 | 12.5 |
| Mon | B | 11 | NA |
| Tue | B | 13 | NA |
| Wed | B | 12 | 11.5 |
| Thu | B | 13 | 12.5 |
| Mon | C | 14 | NA |
| Tue | C | 10 | NA |
| Wed | C | 13 | 11.5 |
| Thu | C | 12 | 12.5 |

I tired the following but doesnt seem to work:

```
df_mean<-  df %>% 
  group_by(Date) %>% 
  mutate(RollingMean = rollmean(Value, n = 2)) %>% 
  ungroup()
```

Any idea? I aim to plot the SMA with the other IDs on the same plot afterward. I would like to have also the rolling median.

Comment: Try to group by `ID`, not by `Date`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `rollmeanr` from package `zoo`. The data is grouped by `ID`, not by date like in the question.

```r
df1 <- read.table(text = "
Date    ID  Value
Mon     A   10
Tue     A   11
Wed     A   15
Thu     A   12
Mon     B   11
Tue     B   13
Wed     B   12
Thu     B   13
Mon     C   14
Tue     C   10
Wed     C   13
Thu     C   12", header = TRUE)

suppressPackageStartupMessages({
  library(dplyr)
})

df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(RollingMean = zoo::rollmeanr(Value, k = 2, fill = NA_real_)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 12 × 4
#>    Date  ID    Value RollingMean
#>    <chr> <chr> <int>       <dbl>
#>  1 Mon   A        10        NA  
#>  2 Tue   A        11        10.5
#>  3 Wed   A        15        13  
#>  4 Thu   A        12        13.5
#>  5 Mon   B        11        NA  
#>  6 Tue   B        13        12  
#>  7 Wed   B        12        12.5
#>  8 Thu   B        13        12.5
#>  9 Mon   C        14        NA  
#> 10 Tue   C        10        12  
#> 11 Wed   C        13        11.5
#> 12 Thu   C        12        12.5
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

Note that the rolling median is trickier. If the window width is `k = 2` then there is no difference from the mean value of those 2 vector elements. This is computed in `RollingMedian2`. If you want `k = 3`, then you can use `rollmedianr`, which needs a window of odd width. That's the case for `RollingMedian3`.

```r
df1 %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>% 
  mutate(RollingMean = zoo::rollmeanr(Value, k = 2, fill = NA_real_),
         RollingMedian2 = zoo::rollapplyr(Value, width = 2, FUN = median, fill = NA_real_),
         RollingMedian3 = zoo::rollmedianr(Value, k = 3, fill = NA_real_)) %>% 
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 12 × 6
#>    Date  ID    Value RollingMean RollingMedian2 RollingMedian3
#>    <chr> <chr> <int>       <dbl>          <dbl>          <dbl>
#>  1 Mon   A        10        NA             NA               NA
#>  2 Tue   A        11        10.5           10.5             NA
#>  3 Wed   A        15        13             13               11
#>  4 Thu   A        12        13.5           13.5             12
#>  5 Mon   B        11        NA             NA               NA
#>  6 Tue   B        13        12             12               NA
#>  7 Wed   B        12        12.5           12.5             12
#>  8 Thu   B        13        12.5           12.5             13
#>  9 Mon   C        14        NA             NA               NA
#> 10 Tue   C        10        12             12               NA
#> 11 Wed   C        13        11.5           11.5             13
#> 12 Thu   C        12        12.5           12.5             12
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

---

## Edit

If I understand the OP's comment, the question asks to compute the average rolling means by group of `ID`. If this is right, then the code below does not output the same values as in the question.

I left the column `RollingMean_by_ID` to show what calculations are being performed.

```r
# used to order the weekdays
date_order <- c("Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu")

df1 %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(Date = factor(Date, levels = date_order),
         RollingMean_by_ID = zoo::rollmeanr(Value, k = 3, fill = NA_real_)) %>% #print()
  group_by(Date) %>%
  mutate(RollingMean = mean(RollingMean_by_ID))
#> # A tibble: 12 × 5
#> # Groups:   Date [4]
#>    Date  ID    Value RollingMean_by_ID RollingMean
#>    <fct> <chr> <int>             <dbl>       <dbl>
#>  1 Mon   A        10              NA          NA  
#>  2 Tue   A        11              NA          NA  
#>  3 Wed   A        15              12          12.1
#>  4 Thu   A        12              12.7        12.3
#>  5 Mon   B        11              NA          NA  
#>  6 Tue   B        13              NA          NA  
#>  7 Wed   B        12              12          12.1
#>  8 Thu   B        13              12.7        12.3
#>  9 Mon   C        14              NA          NA  
#> 10 Tue   C        10              NA          NA  
#> 11 Wed   C        13              12.3        12.1
#> 12 Thu   C        12              11.7        12.3
```

<sup>Created on 2023-09-04 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: This is wrong as in this case i would get a new coulmn that skips the first 2 only but then runs untiil the end. i need it to skip the first 2 rows for each ID, and return the same average to the other rows for each ID. So that later, i can plot xaxis = Date and y-axis= value, and there i will have 4 lines: 3 IDs and 1 moving average (which of course will be missing a small chuck of line given that it skips Mon and Tue)

Comment: @Mining See if the edit solves it.

Comment: what is levels = date_order? it doesnt recognize it. if i take it off, it gives me the rolling mean of the ID as before and the rolling mean i want returns NA

Comment: No this is not working, I see what you are trying to do and what I get is a mixed rolling mean that doesnt reset when the new ID starts. 
You are trying to create a rolling mean by ID which should thus reset as the new ID starts, and then make the mean of those rolling means, but it is not working from the beginning.

Comment: @Mining The column `RollingMean_by_ID` are rolling means by id that *do* reset at the beginning of each id. I have once again verified by hand. Can you edit the question with the calculations you are performing? It might explain the algorithm you want better, by example.

Comment: @Mining, This answer seems to be correct to me.  If you believe that the  expected output shown in the question is really what you want you will need toedit the question to clarify the question by showing exactly how you got those numbers.